# Проблема при передачи данных между web-страницей и службой WCF

Tags: jquery, wcf

Здравствуйте! Получаю ID с web-страницы посредством следующего JQuery.SOAP-скрипта:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('tr').click(function () {        
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.soap({
        url: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/",
        method: "OrdersByPassport",
        SOAPAction: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/OrdersByPassport",            
        soap11: true,
        data: '<passport>'+ id + '</passport>',
        error: function (soapresponse) {
            alert("Oh no is error: " + soapresponse.toString());
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("OK " + result.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

});

Скрипт вызывает Operation Contract WCF-службы:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/OrdersByPassport")]
    [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string OrdersByPassport(int passport);
```

...

```
public string OrdersByPassport(int passport)
    {
        Repository repository = new Repository();
        Query_result qr = new Query_result();
        qr.data = repository.GetOrdersByPassport(passport);
        return (qr.ToString());
    }
```

При использовании тестового клиента WCF проблем не возникает. При взаимодействии web-страницы со службой возникает ошибка при передаче данных из службы: "Ошибка десериализации тела сообщения запроса для операции "OrdersByPassport". OperationFormatter обнаружил недопустимое тело сообщения. Ожидался тип узла "Element" с именем "OrdersByPassport" и пространством имен "http://C_M_Service". Найден тип узла "Element" с именем "passport" и пространством имен """. Просьба помочь с данной проблемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы присылаете данные не в том формате, в котором их ожидает сервис. Формат, который ожидает сервис, есть на странице описания, которая открывается при запуске проекта в браузере (если вы хостите сервис в iis). У вас она скорее всего будет доступна по ссылке вида http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/OrdersByPassport?wsdl.

Сейчас сервис ожидает что-то вроде

```
<OrdersByPassport xmlns="http://C_M_Service">
    тут что-то еще
</OrdersByPassport>
```

а вы ему отправляете что-то вроде

```
<passport>42<passport>
```

Вы должны прислать запрос именно в том виде, в котором его ожидает сервис.

Возьмите любой отладчик http (например, fiddler), или хотя бы консоль network в dev tools браузера.

Запишите запрос от тестового клиента (а лучше - от тестовой формы со страницы справки сервиса в браузере). И потом меняйте свой код отправки, пока формат запроса полностью не совпадет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сервис работает с данными SOAP (прописано в конфигурационном файле). Пробовал делать так, как вы предлагаете, раньше: отправлял из службы, то что выдавал на выходе тестовый клиент. Ошибка осталась. Хостом службы является Windows-служба, fiddler использую, и он выдаёт то же, что alert в скрипте. Не могу понять, откуда элемент "passport" в ответе службы, ведь это входящие данные. Он не входит в Data Contract. WSDL открыл, но не очень понимаю, что здесь смотреть.

Comment: @AN90 Запишите запрос от тестового клиента и попробуйте отправить его  точную копию, вплоть до неймспейса. У вас сейчас служба падает из-за того, что вы ей элемент `OrdersByPassport` не присылаете. И судя по коду - да, не присылаете.

Comment: Действительно, этот элемент не отсылается. Причём не отсылается даже когда в скрипте прописываю его в data. Это какие-то странности JQuery.SOAP или я чего-то не понимаю? А вообще сообщение, которое формирует JQuery.SOAP, значительно отличается от сообщения тестового клиента.

Comment: Разобрался. Изменённый скрипт перезагрузился только после перезапуска браузера.